# Vue JS not rendering the value attribute of Option elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, vue.js

I've got a weird thing going on using a *Select* element with Vue JS:
The following code:

```
<select id="nameDd" v-model="name" >
    <option v-for="n in names" v-bind:value="n.key" " >
        {{ n.value }}
    </option>
</select>
```

renders the *Select* without the *Value* attribute in the *Options* elements:

```
<select id="nameDd">
    <option>Carol</option>
    <option>Carl</option>
    <option>Clara</option>
</select>
```

This of course means that the correct *Option* cannot be selected when required. In my scenario an entry in a table is clicked and the edit form is shown (using v-show) but the *Select* remains empty instead of selecting the right value. In the background, the v-model 'name' does have the right value.

Confusingly, as soon as I select one *Option*, it adds the *Value* attribute:

```
<select id="nameDd">
    <option value="1">Carol</option>
    <option value="2">Carl</option>
    <option value="3">Clara</option>
</select>
```

Now the (even more) confusing part. This actually shows the *Value* attribute in the *Option* elements:

```
<select id="nameDd" v-model="name" >
    <option v-for="n in names" v-bind:value="n.key+'X'" " >
        {{ n.value }}
    </option>
</select>
```

...but of course with an appended X, which again avoids the right *Option* being selected.

**- Is this some VueJs feature that I don't get? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: is there a way to rebind the _Select_ or - as a workaround - select one _Option_ (or trigger the change event of the _Select_) to retrieve the _values_ and then select the right one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is there a second double-quote (`"`) after `v-bind:value` in the `option` tag?

```html
<option v-for="n in names" v-bind:value="n.key" " >
```

I can't find any other issue with your code. I practically wrote the same code again and it worked. Here is a working jsFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/3x0z3vzk/

As you can see, I really don't have much code, just the 3 lines:

```html
<select v-model="selectedPerson">
    <option v-for="person in people" :value="person.key">{{person.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I don't know if the second double quote was causing the issue. Vue expects perfect markup so that it can do its model-view bindings properly. When I tried to put a stray double-quote like yours, I got a console error, not the missing option value that you noticed.

I hope this example helps to fix your code!